# Can I get the returned credit card details after creating a Stripe customer that includes a source (credit card)?

Tags: c#, stripe-payments

Using Stripe to create a new customer, like below, I'm adding a source (credit card) to the customer in the form of a token id. After the customer is created I can see the source id is returned, but the data is not.

**QUESTION** - Is it possible to have the customer fetch the data so that I don't have to perform another request, from Stripe, to get the card details?

Here is a simple example

```
StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = "sk_test_1234";
var options = new CustomerCreateOptions {
       Email = "email,
       Name = "name,
       Source = "12345" // card token number here
};
var service = new CustomerService();
customer = service.Create(options);
```

Here is what I see when the customer returns.
You can see the defaultSourceId (card) but the DefaultSource is null. It would be nice if it returned the details (brand, lastfour, exp month, exp year, etc) otherwise I have to perform another call to Stripe to fetch the card details.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A customer's sources is no longer included by default when creating or retrieving the customer: https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/object#customer_object-sources

If you still want to retrieve the sources list, you'd have to expand your customer creation call: https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects

For example:

```cs
StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = "sk_test_1234";
var options = new CustomerCreateOptions {
       Email = "email,
       Name = "name,
       Source = "12345" // card token number here
};
// Request the full list of sources attached to this customer
options.AddExpand("sources");

var service = new CustomerService();
customer = service.Create(options);
```